# search function without required login

Tags: php, laravel, search

this is a search function that should log in to view the search blade.
I want to show the search blade without required student login and allow anyone to use this function

this is my search function in the controller

```
public function search()
{
    $q = Input::get ( 'q' );
    if($q != ""){
        $student = Student::where ( 'uniid', 'LIKE', '%' . $q . '%' )->get();
        if (count ( $student ) > 0)
            return view ( 'search' )->withDetails ( $student )->withQuery ( $q );
        else
            return view ( 'search' )->withMessage ( 'not fount' );
    }
    return view ( 'search' )->withMessage ( 'write the number want to search' );
}
```

and this my search blade

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <title>Search</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
  <form action="/search" method="POST" role="search">
  {{ csrf_field() }}
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="q"
        placeholder="search.."> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
        </button>
    </span>
</div>
</form>
 <div class="container">
@if(isset($details))
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> unique id</th>
            <th>  order statuse</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($details as $request)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$request->uniid}}</td>
            <td>{{$request->status->name}}</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
@elseif(isset($message))
<p>{{ $message }}</p>
@endif
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Show us your web.php routes file. If theres no auth middleware injected to the route there shouldn't be a restriction for logged in users so this should work.

Comment: //search
Route::post('/search','StudentController@search');
Route::get('/search','StudentController@search');

Comment: So you want that not authenticated users can access the search page and search for a student? Have you tested it correctly because it should work. If you don't use the 'auth' middleware in your ``web.php`` routes file or somewhere else everyone can access this page. So eventually I'm missunderstanding your question but your code should work for the case you described. If not post more details about the problem like error messages, log output and the complete controller and web routes file.

Comment: Just remove middleware:auth from the route or the controller